# Can't connect to localhost ruby (no framework) in vagrant

Tags: ruby, vagrant

everyone!
I'm writing simple web app on ruby (without using any framework), and everything works fine when i try it on my local machine (ubuntu), but I can't connect it on Vagrant.
Here is Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/install-rvm.sh", args: "stable", privileged: false
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/install-ruby.sh", args: "1.9.3", privileged: false
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/install-ruby.sh", args: "2.3.1 rails haml", privileged: false
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/install-bundler.sh", privileged: false
end
```

app.rb :

```
class App
  def call(env)
    [200, {}, ['Hello world']]
  end
end
```

config.ru :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require "./app"
run App.new
```

Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile 
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby '2.3.1'
gem 'rack'
gem 'puma'
```

After I run rackup command it says:

```
Listening on tcp://localhost:9292
```

But I can't connect to it. I already tried to change host port from Vagrantfile, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is

> `Listening on tcp://localhost:9292`

You're starting your app on localhost (inside the VM) so it cannot be accessed from your host.

You need to change the way you start your app so it listens on `0.0.0.0` so all network interfaces can access it.

Make sure to add a forwarding port with the port that you start your app, as above it start on 9292, add a line in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9292, host: 9292
```

so that you can access correctly your app

Comment: ok so you need to forward port 8080 in your Vagranfile, not 80 and you should be able to access it

Comment: now I'm running it on 0.0.0.0 using command 
` rackup -o 0.0.0.0 -p 8080`
so it says:
`* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8080}`